# Drools not working as intended. In when section object status doesn't change. How do I make it update?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

Intention is to rule to activate when TradeEvent with specific book name appears, and PanicButtonManager panic mode is enabled:

```
when
   $tradeEvent : TradeEvent(
   bookShortName == "FMBTHQLA")
   p : PanicButtonManager(
      panicModeEnabled)
```

The thing is that when I change field panicModeEnabled value in drools it's not updated. The field value is constant from time of PanicButtonManager creation. But when I try to "print" it it's working fine:

```
when
   $tradeEvent : TradeEvent(
   bookShortName == "FMBTHQLA");
   p : PanicButtonManager(
      panicModeEnabled)
then      
   modify ($tradeEvent){
      messageCode = "PM003",
      message = "HQLA: FMBTHQLA is restricted to HQLA mode. Panic status: " + p.isPanicModeEnabled(),
      tradeValidationStatus = STATUS.ERROR
   }
```

This code activated whenever new TradeEvent appears with specific book name, but second condition stays same even tho I change panicMode field. But at the same time in message it prints correct status(it changes).

Why in "when" section evaluation of panicModeEnabled stays same? It keeps value from creation of class PanicButtonManager and doesn't update with change of field, but field prints correctly in message.

How do I make PanicButtonManager evaluate correctly in when section(Not keep state from creation time but update with field update).

Comment: `second condition stays same even tho I change panicMode field` -> can you please show how you "change the panicMode field"? Your example is only changing the state of the TradeEvent, but not the state of the PanicButtonManager.

Comment: Also a bit more detail on these models would be helpful in understanding how they relate to each other.

Comment: State of the PanicButtonManager is changed outside of drools. Whenever I invoke new TradeEvent I pass panicMode field value to the message and it works. The value passed is changing and printed correctly. The thing is that the state of PanicButtonManager inside the drools stays the same. Even tho the field is changed for the drools it stays the same. For the more details on the models. Basically you can imagine that Trade Event is what name says. Whenever something is getting traded event is created. Panic mode is restriction to those trades. When it's on not everyone is allowed to trade.

Comment: External changes are not visible if you don't call `update` on PanicButtonManager. `modify` is making the trade event changes visible, but the PanicButtonManager's previous state is retained because you've not informed Drools of new state.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the state of PanicButtonManager is modified outside of Drools. Therefore to make the changed state visible, you need to call `update` to trigger a reevaluation of the rules with the new value. The `modify` is only making the new state of the TradeEvent visible.

The syntax would be like this:

```
rule "..."
when
  // ...
  p: PanicButtonManager( panicModeEnabled )
then
  // ...
  update(p);
end
```

Note that `update` will reevaluate all of the rules with the new condition(s), not just the remaining rules in the previous set of matches.

Comment: The thing is that since it's updated outside of drools i need to have the new state in "when" section. If it's updated in "then" the other rules would evaluate inappropriate. TradeEvent on the other side is always new and created with factory and injected. What i did to temporary fix the issue with panic button manager is I inject it into TradeEvent but I feel like it's inappropriate

Comment: That's what `update` does. It updates the value in working memory ("in the when") and refires all of the rules to see what is now valid to match on. Changing it "in the then" is inappropriate.